# Cast slice of chan to slice of output chan

Tags: go, slice

I want to return a `[]<-chan int` given a `[]chan int` from a function, but even casting doesn't work.

You **can** assign a `chan T` to a `chan<- T` or a `<-chan T` (implicit type conversion). I'm not sure why you **can't** do the same for a slice of chans.  AFAIK the `<-` is just a compile time thing (like `const` in other languages) and the memory layout of a `chan` and `<-chan` is the same.

I can provide a full example of the code but essentially this is what I want to do:

```
func f() []<-chan int {
    var chanList []chan int
    // setup writing to chans
    return chanList
}
```

This gives a compile error: cannot use `[]<-chan int` as `[]chan int`. The same thing happens if I use a type cast.  Copying the whole slice into a new slice works, but seems ugly and redundant (and inefficient for a huge slice).

Comment: Would those contributors who voted down my question kindly explain why. I think it is a good question and I have tried several things (cast and copying) and have done quite a bit of searching (here and other places) to no avail.

Comment: "AFAIK the <- is just a compile time thing (like const in other languages)" No. "and the memory layout of a chan and <-chan is the same" Yes but irrelevant: T and S in `type T  int; type S int` have the same memory layout  but you cannot  convert a []S to a []T and that is what the compiler tells you.

Comment: Thanks @Volker I appreciate what you are saying but that is slightly different.  You can't convert a []S to a []T but you can't convert an S to a T.  There is a good reason for this.  On the other hand you can convert a `chan int` to a `<-chan int` so why not a `[]chan int` to a `[]<-chan int`. This is reasonable if you think carefully. Also, I am not sure what you mean by *No* - I have confirmed looking at assembly that adding <- to a type decl. does not affect the code generated.

Comment: I did further research and found that there is at least one other person who has encountered this issue (see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40010). I think we need to propose a change to the language.

Answer (score 1):

In Go, `[]<-chan int` and `[]chan int` are treated as different things. Although they might shared exactly same memory structure.

How about wrapping your implementation in a customized struct ?

```golang
package main

// roCh denotes a readonly channel
type roCh chan int

// Read is an exposed method for reading this channel
func (r roCh) Read() int { return <-r } 

func newChannels(n int) []roCh {
    roChs := make([]roCh, n)
    
    for i := range roChs {
        roChs[i] = roCh(make(chan int, 1))
        
        // Apply your channel logic here...
        // ...
    }
    
    return roChs
}

func main() {
    chs := newChannels(5)
    for _ = range chs {
        // channel readonly operation...
        // chs[i].Read()
    }
}
```

You may hide the detail of your reading channels from users. It could force a caller to use the method `Read` for reading the content of these channels.

Comment: I like your thinking. I might be able to create a struct with private `[]chan int` field to only allow reading from the chans. I'll have to try it out and get back to you.  (I have a large number of methods with `[]<-chan int` receiver type, which I may be able to change to use a `struct {[]chan int}` )